# Command Prompt/Batch - rename multiple files with sequential numbering

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-rename

Lets say I have multiple files

```
filename.a.txt
filename.b.txt
filename.c.txt
```

I want to run a batch file that targets all .txt files and rename them to whatever I have set into my custom %filename% var + give them numbers so it would end up into something like:

```
filename.1.txt
filename.2.txt
filename.3.txt
```

So far I have wrote this:

```
set filename=FileTitle
for /r %%i in (*.txt) do call ren %%i %filename%.txt
```

And it works, but problem is that it just picks up first .txt file and gives it the FileTitle filename and that's it. I can't figure how to rename all .txt files in a batch and give them unique sequential number as a prefix/suffix/custom var to the outputed `%filename%.txt` so something like e.g. `%filename%-%uniquesuffix%.txt`. So I need to set some kind of variable that gives each file a unique number e.g. from 1-99 in alphabet order (default order that cmd prompt picked files up).

I did search other answers, but they show only how to add global/same prefix to renamed files.

Comment: Well I am pretty sure we have an example on SO.  If you need a sequence number then set a variable to increment each time it renames a file with the `SET /A` command.  No reason to use the `CALL` command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set filename=FileTitle
set suffix=100
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /B *.txt') do (
   set /A suffix+=1
   ren "%%i" "%filename%-!suffix:~1!.txt"
)
```

This code renames the files in the form you requested. Note that the numeric suffix have *two digits* in order to preserve the original *alphabet order* of the files. If "natural" 1-99 numbers were used, then the order in that cmd prompt show the files is changed in this way: `1.txt 10.txt 11.txt ... 19.txt 2.txt 20.txt 21.txt ... 29.txt 3.txt ...` (*alphabet order*, NOT numeric one). If may be more than 99 files, just add another zero in `set suffix=100` command to generate a three-digits suffix.

Note also that your plain `for` command may process some files *twice or more times* depending on the site where the renamed files will be placed in the original files list. To avoid this problem use a `for /F` command over a `dir /B *.txt` one. This method *first* get a list of all files, and *then* execute the renames over such a static list.

To process all files under current folder (that is the purpose of your `/r` switch in `for` command), just add a `/S` switch in the `dir` command.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, maybe you know how I rename to 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, 11 instead of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following code to do the job.

```
@echo off
pushd %~dp0
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set filename=FileTitle
set Num=1
for /r %%i in (*.txt) do (
    ren "%%i" "%filename%.!Num!.txt"
    set /a Num+=1
)
```

You can look at https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html to see how the code works.